# A interesting phenomenon between original function and its inverse.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I find a surprising phenomenon when doing homework:

> Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are mutually inverse functions and all variables meets the domain regulations,so we have the surprising results: "$f(g(x))=x$" or more amazing "$f(g(Φ(x)))=Φ(x)$"($Φ(x)$ is just function unrelated to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$)

Maybe this is not freshed. But I want to know does the phenomenon has some limits more detailed? How to demonstrate it (I can only vaguely understand it from the relationship between original function and its inverse function)?

Comment: What's amazing? This is just from the definition of f and g being mutually inverse: $f(g(x)) = x$ for every $x$ in the domain of $g$, and $g(f(x)) = x$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Comment: maybe I don’t understand it deeply enough